# How to make a call when iphone shakes with particular threshold?

Tags: iphone, iphone-vibrate

I am making an app in which i need to implement calling emergency medical services when mobile shakes with a particular threshold.
Is it possible to capture the threshold or the extent of phone shakes and making a call when it happens?
One requirement is can this is possible when my app is not running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the iPhone does not allow applications to run in the background. So the answer to your second questions is: No, this is not possible when your app is not running.

Comment: ok...
but do you know how to capture the threshold of phone vibrations?
do you have any sample code for that?

Comment: Nope, sorry. I have not much experience programming for the iphone.